# SVG file warning message in Android Studio editor

Tags: android, svg, xml-namespaces, android-studio-2.0

I'm using Android Studio 2.0 with SVG2VectorDrawable:

[image: Plugin dialog]

If I open a svg file for edit from the `\RAW` resource folder, the file i underlined with the red color and a warning message "element svg must be declared" is shown as below:

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?

**I'm using the SVG plugin only for the editor extension that allows the correct viewing of the SVG XML format**

This is the svg file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="9.693px" height="22.8px" viewBox="0 0 9.693 22.8" enable-background="new 0 0 9.693 22.8" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#616161" d="M7.703,14.038c1.248,0.911,1.99,2.36,1.99,3.916
    c0,2.677-2.17,4.847-4.847,4.847C2.17,22.8,0,20.63,0,17.954c0-1.555,0.743-3.006,1.99-3.916V2.856C1.99,1.281,3.271,0,4.846,0
    c1.577,0,2.856,1.279,2.856,2.856C7.702,6.583,7.702,10.311,7.703,14.038L7.703,14.038z M4.769,11.374h1.115V9.616H4.769V8.983
    h1.115V7.225H4.769V6.593h1.115V4.834H4.769V4.202h1.115V2.856c0-0.573-0.464-1.037-1.037-1.037c-0.573,0-1.037,0.468-1.037,1.037
    v11.42c0,0.47-0.223,0.885-0.618,1.142c-0.855,0.559-1.373,1.508-1.373,2.536c0,1.673,1.355,3.028,3.027,3.028
    c1.673,0,3.028-1.355,3.028-3.028c0-1.027-0.517-1.976-1.373-2.536c-0.396-0.258-0.618-0.667-0.618-1.142v-2.27H4.769V11.374
    L4.769,11.374z M4.899,20.528c0.132,0,0.239-0.108,0.239-0.239l0-0.478c0-0.132-0.108-0.239-0.239-0.239
    c-0.666,0-1.207-0.54-1.207-1.206c0-0.131-0.107-0.239-0.239-0.239H2.976c-0.131,0-0.239,0.108-0.239,0.239
    C2.736,19.56,3.705,20.528,4.899,20.528z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: what's your minimum sdk version?

Comment: It's too late and maybe you have found out the reason too but if not then check my  updated answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As described in the following links  you **can't use** `.svg` files **directly** in your project. They first need to be converted into corresponding xml file . To do that you can use Vector Asset Studio.
Here are those links

[Svg in Android Studio](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/android-studio-svg.html)

and

[Importing svg file in Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html#svg)

If you are missing jar files required for it you can get it from here alongwith the tutorial also

[SVG Integration in Android](http://android-coffee.com/svg-integration-in-android-studio/)

**UPDATE**

I now understood the real problem for this error. This error occurs when you directly copy the svg file into your project. To be able to use svg properly, **you need to import it as a vector asset.**

Comment: Sorry but this answer is not suitable for me. I'm trying to solve the warning message in the Android Studio XML editor. I update the question. Thanks anyway

Comment: do you have the jar files required for svg?